# Problem with umlauts in glossary

Tags: glossaries, characters

The following code does not produce umlauts as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{a}{%
name={A},%
description={a \"a {\"a} ä}%
}

\begin{document}
\glsentrydesc{a}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I tried several variants. Oddly enough, in the glossary itself (produced with `\printglossary`) all variants for the umlaut work.

How should I use `\glsentrydesc` to get a correct result?

Comment: `description` is mainly meant for usage in the glossary. Do `\usepackage[sanitize={description=false}]{glossaries}` if you want to use `\glsentrydesc` in the text.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. This also fixes the case when the description is shown in normal uses with `\gls`, and changed `\glsdisplay(first)`. If you make it an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `description` field is mainly meant for usage in the glossary section and for this reason (safe writing in the `.glo` file) it is usually sanitized, that is, transformed into a string.

You can call `glossaries` with the following option

```
\usepackage[sanitize={description=false}]{glossaries}
```

if you need to call `\glsentrydesc` in the text before typesetting the glossary. See section 2.1 in the package documentation.